# Returning focus to input after submit

Tags: jquery, focus

I'm trying to clear the content of the input on submit (which works) and then refocus on the field so the user can automatically start typing again.

```
$("#submitMessage").submit(function() {
    $("#messageText").attr("value", "");
    $("#messageText").focus();
})
```

The field is cleared when I do it this way but focus is not given back to element. Any ideas?

-- EDIT --

I was calling the function on the button as opposed to the form itself. It always just fine when switching that around.

Comment: Is your form submitted by AJAX or does submission reload the same page?

Comment: The form is submitted by AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

If the page reloads after the submit, add the the focus code to the document.ready.

Comment: It doesn't. I'm using Ajax.